# AWS Server-Side Encryption C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Hi we are trying to use AWS S3 to upload and get files URL with Encryption .

We are using this code to Upload:

```
  using (var client = GetS3ClientConnection(AccessKey, SecretKey, RegionEndpoint))
{
var request = new PutObjectRequest
   {
        BucketName = FilePathInS3,
        Key = FileNameInS3,
        ServerSideEncryptionCustomerMethod = ServerSideEncryptionCustomerMethod.AES256,
        ServerSideEncryptionCustomerProvidedKey = base64Key //= "Is this ServerSideEncryptionKeyManagementServiceKeyId?"
    };
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(fileByteArray))
    {
        request.InputStream = ms;
        client.PutObject(request);
    }
}
```

And this to Get:

```
using (var client = GetS3ClientConnection(AccessKey, SecretKey, RegionEndpoint))
{
    GetPreSignedUrlRequest request = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest
    {
        BucketName = FilePathInS3,
        Key = FileNameInS3,
        Expires = 1,
        Protocol = Protocol.HTTP,
        ServerSideEncryptionKeyManagementServiceKeyId = "KEY"
    };
    url = client.GetPreSignedURL(request);
}
```

When we get the URL and try to access it, we got access denied invalid Key.

What is wrong?, please help.

Comment: You use the wrong method for retrieving. You put an SSE-C encrypted file into bucket but want to retrieve it with SSE-KMS. ;)
And if you want to retrieve the file with a presigned url, the key must be sent as header value.

Answer (score 0):

I think In order to do encryption/deencryption with AmazonS3 and c# you need to set the following Properies of PutObjectRequest and GetObjectRequest object:

- ServerSideEncryptionCustomerMethod =AES256
- ServerSideEncryptionCustomerProvidedKey=base64(secretkey)
- ServerSideEncryptionCustomerProvidedKeyMD5 : md5(base64(secretkey))

Code Example with c#:

```
            var amazonS3Config = new AmazonS3Config();
            amazonS3Config.RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.USEast1;// use your region endpoint
            var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client("your access key", "your secret key", amazonS3Config);
            PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest();
            request.BucketName = "your bucket name";
            request.Key = "your file key name";
            request.InputStream = File.Open(@"d:\SmallData\Doc1.pdf", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            // please generate your own keys 
            String CustomerKey = "qsiFY0xPeBtZn55eaT6i/bFLgpkO30QKNucYMGlbnck=";
            String CustomerKeyMD5 = "RyOu+4ghh+CgGcPryIvPdw==";

            request.ServerSideEncryptionCustomerMethod = ServerSideEncryptionCustomerMethod.AES256;                
            request.ServerSideEncryptionCustomerProvidedKey = CustomerKey;
            request.ServerSideEncryptionCustomerProvidedKeyMD5 = CustomerKeyMD5;
            s3Client.PutObject(request); // save the file encrypted to amazonS3
```

to retrieve encrypted content from AmazonS3:

```
        GetObjectRequest getRequest = new GetObjectRequest();
        getRequest.BucketName = "your bucket name";
        getRequest.Key = "your file key name";
        getRequest.ServerSideEncryptionCustomerMethod = ServerSideEncryptionCustomerMethod.AES256;
        getRequest.ServerSideEncryptionCustomerProvidedKey = CustomerKey;
        getRequest.ServerSideEncryptionCustomerProvidedKeyMD5 = CustomerKeyMD5;
        using (GetObjectResponse response = s3Client.GetObject(getRequest))
        {
            using (Stream test = response.ResponseStream)
            { 
                using(FileStream file = new FileStream(@"d:\SmallData\result\test.pdf", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                {
                    CopyStream(test, file);
                }
            }
        }
```

I hope this can help you.
some reference links about it are the following:
https://sprightlysoft.com/blog/?p=209
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/111202/aws-s3-server-side-encryption-client-provided-keys-php
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/SSEUsingDotNetSDK.html