# How to use AWS AES-256 in AWS Lambda C#

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

Beginner here. How can I access an encrypted bucket. I read the documentation and it doesnt clearly state how will I create an encrypted bucket besides the default encryption option and bucket policy. I cant use a KMS key for the encryption

I checked this [AWS Server-Side Encryption C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43814871/aws-server-side-encryption-c-sharp) but I dont know where I will get the following

```
 ServerSideEncryptionCustomerMethod =AES256
 ServerSideEncryptionCustomerProvidedKey=base64(secretkey)
 ServerSideEncryptionCustomerProvidedKeyMD5 : md5(base64(secretkey))
```

Could you please simplify or discuss the steps.

Comment: Are you trying to access an encrypted bucket or create one?

Comment: Are you trying to supply the encryption key yourself, or are you expecting AWS to do server-side encryption for you with *their* managed keys?

Comment: @LeeGaines I am trying to create one

Comment: @jarmod expecting AWS to do the server side encryption but can I also supply the encryption key?

Comment: Yes, that's termed SSE-C (Server Side Encryption with Customer-provided keys). Take a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/sse-c-using-dot-net-sdk.html

Comment: By the way, I don't think you can create an S3 bucket that encrypts using SSE-C by default - your choices are SSE-S3 or SSE-KMS (both of which use AWS-managed keys). If you want to use customer-provided keys then you need to supply them on every put.

Comment: @jarmod does this encrypt the bucket and all the contents? The confusing part is do I have to set anything in the bucket?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179777/discussion-between-jarmod-and-john).